# jQuery keydown not reading tab key the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, keypress, keydown

I am making a chrome extension and am trying to use jQuery's keydown function, but it has the following problem:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 65) {
        //code here
    }
});
```

This code works fine when pressing the a key, while the following function is never executed (even outside the if statement) on the first tab press but is afterwards:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 9) {
        //code here
    }
});
```

I couldn't find anyone who was having this problem, so I thought I'd post it.

Comment: I tried `document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {...});` and it works fine for `tab` too. Where did you putthe above code ? What is your extension structure ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem Interesting. I am putting the listener inside a window.onload function, in the main popup window. I have the same results with document.addEventListener().

Comment: Do you have any other listeners that might intercept that ? Did you say it does not work the first time you press `tab`, but it works afterwards ?

Comment: No, there are no other keydown listeners. Nothing happens when the tab key is first pressed, but it triggers every time after.